# Regarding new rules for getting a tourist visa for Egypt

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, egypt

I am a Canadian citizen, visiting in Malaysia right now, want to go to Egypt. I read the rules for visas changed in March 2015, but also read that change was reversed or something. I'm wondering if anyone would know if I can get a visa when I arrive there or not.

Comment: I'm curious where did you read the rules had changed ?

Comment: @blackbird57: No idea where the OP saw it, but it's mentioned on [Visa policy of Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Egypt) (with sources).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can still get a visa on arrival in Egypt, quoting the Egyptian [embassy](http://www.egyptianconsulate.co.uk/visas.php) in London:

> In addition to UK and EU nationals, citizens of the following
>   countries can obtain visa upon arrival at any of the Egyptian ports of
>   entry: Australia, Canada, Croatia, Georgia, Japan, New Zealand,
>   Norway, Macedonia, Republic of Korea, Russian Federation, Serbia,
>   Ukraine and USA.

The Timatic-based [web tool](http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=CA&NV=Canada&DC=EG&DV=Egypt&h=6c93966b4cc5cf20b7ef21b062577c1210bacde) from Emirates also says the same thing

> Holders of normal passports issued to nationals of Canada can obtain a
>   visa on arrival for a max. stay of 30 days. Fee: single entry: USD
>   25.-; multiple entry USD 35.-.